# Getter returning empty reader value

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to return a string though a Getter, the string is obtained from a DataRead object which loops through the mysql query.  The problem is that, upon load, the string does not get loaded onto the main form's label, it returns an empty string and if I assign a string to the variable upon declaration, it returns that to my main form.  Here's the code:

```
string text;
public string Text { get { return text; } }

public void DBConn()
{
     MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     MySqlDataReader reader = null;

     try
     {
          // connection to DB
          reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
          if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    text = reader["string1"].ToString() + " " + reader["string2"].ToString() + " " + reader["string3"].ToString();
                }
            }
     }
      // try, catch. conn.close()
}
```

The reader is assigning the values onto *text* just fine, but outside of the while, the value is not assigned to the globally declared variable, it seems to get destroyed as soon as it leaves the loop.  Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a local variable called `text` that you might have edited out of your question?  BTW, in this type of scenario rather than declaring the backing variable yourself, you can use `public string Text { get; private set; }` and then assign as `Text = reader...`.  The setter is private to the class when declared in this manner.

Comment: I actaully came accross that but didn't quite get it.  I declared both, the variable and the getter outside of any method, the weird thing is that I have a couple of setters there as well and they do set the value to the class.

Comment: As it is, your loop is resetting the value of text on each iteration. Could it be that the last iteration has an empty value?

Comment: @kailanjian: Good catch, assuming there is more than one iteration.  In that case it will return the last value read.  Also if there are zero iterations, the value of `text` will not change (though the OP says he confirmed that `text` has an appropriate value.

Comment: How are you trying to get the content to the form? DataBinding in WPF? setting variables directly in WinForms? This likely is a problem getting the new `text` value to your UI, not getting a value into `text`.

Comment: @kailanjian: It's weird, I added a messagebox outside of the loop and it shows me the database value stored in the variable text.  It just won't assign it to the Getter for some reason.

Comment: @nekizalb: No, this is plain WinForms and I'm not using databinding, just the one Getter to get this value to my main form and displaying it on a label, so I'm calling
`code` DataBase db = new Database();
`code` lblName.text = db.Text; // This is the getter.

Comment: @hectormtnezg just to clarify, you tested after the while loop, and `text` has a value but `Text` does not?

Comment: @kailanjian: Yes, text keeps the value but after calling Text from my main form it returns an empty string.  It's weird I know, I may be missing something on the declaration of my getter.

Comment: @hectormtnezg what happens when you call `Text` from within this class? The issue may be in your main class.

Comment: @kailanjian: If I call Text from a MessageBox outside the IF but still inside the Try block it actually returns the value obtained from the DB but if I call Text from anywhere outside the Try block, it returns null even if called within the same method.

Comment: Do you use Fody or any other AOP thing what transforms you assembly after compile?

Comment: @g.pickardou: just VS 2013

Comment: @hectormtnezg: Then my guess is: You are using an _other_ instance of your class when you accessing to the Text property (you call the DBConn() method on a different instance.) Please check it.

Comment: @hectormtnezg - Code shown in the post is unlikely related to issue you have. Please make sure to provide minimal sample that reproduces he issue.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that either a) `Text` is being set in another process or b) being used in another process after declaring a `new` instance of whatever process `Text` actually belongs to. As a few others have mentioned, the issue seems to be occurring outside of this code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those who helped me find the solution to the problem described.  As some of you kindly explained (and I was lacking the knowledge to understand at first until a lot of research was done), the issue turned out to be a problem with my Main form being in a different instance from the first class that calls upon the class that has the Getter in it.  I know now I should have mentioned all of these details in the original post, I apologize to those of you who tried to understand from a small piece of code.  After a lot of research on **Instances**, the solution I came to was to first, create a class that holds static Getters and Setters `public static string Text { set; get; }` (this was how I wanted it for easy access from other classes) this helps in making them accessible from all instances, it might not be the best solution especially on OOP - During my research I read somewhere that using Setters and Getters is a waste of time and not the best practice for programmers, that it is best to encapsulate but because I am still very fresh I will look up how to do that later.

Thank you guys again.